# How to mock socket module in python?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, raspbian, python-unittest

I am working on a multicast project with `python3` and have a small program to search for `upnp` devices on the local network. I want to use `unittest` and `mock` the expensive call to `socket.recvfrom(bufsize[, flags])`.

Here is my program `./upnp/mucassdp.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

class ssdpObj():
# Handle Simple Service Discovery Protocol,
# for discovering UPnP devices on the local network

    def msearch(self):
        msg = \
            'M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n' \
            'HOST:239.255.255.250:1900\r\n' \
            'ST:upnp:rootdevice\r\n' \
            'MX:2\r\n' \
            'MAN:"ssdp:discover"\r\n' \
            '\r\n'

        # Set up UDP socket with timeout and send a M-SEARCH structure
        # to the upnp multicast address and port
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
        s.settimeout(2)
        s.sendto(msg.encode(), ('239.255.255.250', 1900) )

        # print received data within the timeout
        try:
            while True:
                # expensive call to mock for testing
                data, addr = s.recvfrom(65507)

                print (addr, data.decode(), end='')
        except socket.timeout:
            pass
```

And here is my test case `./tests/mucassdpTest.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from upnp.mucassdp import ssdpObj


class mucassdpTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('upnp.mucassdp.socket')
    def test_msearch(self, mock_socket):
        # instantiate our service
        oSsdp = ssdpObj()

        mock_socket.recvfrom.return_value = [0, '1']
        #mock_socket.recvfrom.side_effect = [0, '1']

        oSsdp.msearch()
        mock_socket.settimeout.assert_called_with(2)
```

When I try to run the test case with:

```
~$ python3 -m unittest tests.mucassdpTest
```

I get the error message (only relevant part):

```
ERROR: test_msearch (tests.mucassdpTest.mucassdpTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ingo/devel/muca-tools/upnp/mucassdp.py", line 27, in msearch
    data, addr = s.recvfrom(65507)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

I've looked around and found some similar questions and answers, e.g. initialize `Mock` through its constructor with the expected `data, addr` or setup `side_effect` ( I've tried this) but I cannot get it to run successfully with my test.

How do I have to set up the patched `socket` module to get the expected paired `data, addr` from `s.recvfrom(...)` under test conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you are mocking the `socket` module import in `upnp.mucassdp`, and then trying to configure it with the `recvfrom()` call. However, the `recvfrom()` method exists on the `socket.socket` class, not the `socket` module.

```py
@patch('upnp.mucassdp.socket')
def test_msearch(self, mock_socket):
    # mock_socket is the module, not the socket class
```

The way to resolve is to patch the `socket.socket` class, and then in the test, retrieve the instance before configuring it.

```py
class mucassdpTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('upnp.mucassdp.socket.socket')  # Patch the class
    def test_msearch(self, mock_socket):
        mock_socket = mock_socket.return_value  # We want the instance

        # instantiate our service
        oSsdp = ssdpObj()

        mock_socket.recvfrom.return_value = [0, '1']
        #mock_socket.recvfrom.side_effect = [0, '1']

        oSsdp.msearch()
        mock_socket.settimeout.assert_called_with(2)
```